# Can xcode be configured to always display the files navigator?

Tags: xcode

When launching/running the application the files `Navigator` panel is overlaid with the `Run` :

[image]

But I need to view the files/directories in the project at the same time - and the breadcrumbs above the editor is insufficient.  Is this configuration possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer but maybe the best workaround.  I discovered that `command-1` shows the `Navigator` and `command-2` Shows the `Run/Debug`.  So that is a reasonable quick-switch approach that allows me to be productive.